# Add Active Class to Current list menu item without using clientside JS/jquery in marko?

Tags: javascript, node.js, marko

i have menu list  and  i want  to  add  active class  on  the  specific menu item  which is  clicked  e.g  if it clicks on contact page  then  contact option in the menu become  active  class.
I am using NodeJS  and  Koa  here is  my  code  of  how iam  rendering my  marko  File `

```
var contact = function*(){
 this.body = marko.load('./views/contact.marko').stream();
 this.type = 'text/html';
 console.log('At Contact Page');
 }
```

am using marko as  views .  and  i dont want  to use  any clientside script

Answer (score 1):

So I trying do this passing the url what is being rendered as an data for the template.
something like this:

```
var contact = function*(){
 this.body = marko.load('./views/contact.marko').stream({url:'/contactpage'});
 this.type = 'text/html';
 console.log('At Contact Page');
 }
```

and in my template I am trying to compare this url parameter with the menus url and placing the class on then. Not fancy, and still trying make work properly